# Nginx testing simulator

Tags: nginx

is there a website that provides for testing the configuration of the Nginx web server? if there is it will make it easier for developers to test the configuration before implementing it in the staging/production environment

Comment: `$ sudo nginx -t`. What are you specifically looking to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about testing locally?  For HTTPS, create a self-signed TLS certificate for the domains you're testing, and use `$ curl --insecure` (`-k`) for those self-signed HTTPS endpoints. Add your test domains to `/etc/hosts` so they hit the local Nginx server:

```
127.0.0.1  example1.com example2.com
```

Test redirects and response headers:

```
$ curl -kLI https://example.com         # HEAD request
$ curl -kLI -X GET https://example.com  # GET request
```

Test content responses

```
$ curl -kL https://example.com
```